# Types of thread in C++

Tags: c++, thread-synchronization

What are the different types of thread in C++ ?
I already know multiprocessing and multi threading . I know how to create threads in normal C++ , VC++ but not sure what is mean by different types of thread.

Comment: There's not so much types of threads as what threads are used for.

Answer (score 3):

From the software point of view, there are no "different types of threads". A thread is a thread. Are there different types of pixels on the screen? Nope. It's similar. However, in some contexts, you MAY differentiate threads over their intended purpose. You can have:

- os threads (or kernel threads) vs user threads (or application threads)
- main thread vs ad-hoc threads vs pooled threads
- background threads vs high-priority threads
- etc

but a thread is a thread. They are all the same in terms of their basic properties: they run some specified code. The difference is in how they are used and what priority they have (= how often they get some processor time to do their work) or what code they are allowed to run.

...ok, thinking a bit more about the terms used in different contexts, ACTUALLY, there are 2 types of threads, and both are just called 'threads':

- software threads
- hardware threads

The difference is that the former one is what the operating system's scheduler manages (creates/wakes/puts to sleep/kills/etc). The number of those is virtually limited only by the available memory. You may have 100-1000-10000 software threads, no problem.. The latter refers to the actual electronic structures that execute them. There's always a much lower limit there. Not long ago each CPU could execute just a single thread. You wanted to run 8 threads? have a 8-cpu motherboard. Today, most CPUs have multiple "cores" and can each can execute several (usually 4-16) threads.

However, in my region, when someone says "a thread", they mean a "a software thread", and when someone wants to refer to the latter, they say explicitly "a hardware thread". That's why I didn't think of this at first, probably I'm more of a software guy, why in a hardware team they may "thread"="hardware thread" by default.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are two types of multitasking: process-based and thread-based.

Process-based multitasking handles the concurrent execution of programs which is something like two people doing same tasks or the first person doing the task & the second person doing the sub-task of the same task.

Thread-based multitasking deals with the concurrent execution of pieces of the same program which is something like you are using different parts of your body for some work ( or say, multitasking ).

I don't know if I my above analogies are correct or not ( in reference to your understanding ).

For further information, you can [follow this link.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20there%20are%20two,pieces%20of%20the%20same%20program.)